# StaggeredGridLayout with dynamic # of objects per row, line-wrapping

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm looking for a way to display a list of images/icons of variable width in my UI with line-wrapping enabled, such that there can be a variable number of objects per line. The list of objects is dynamic and sourced from a DB. I'm currently using a StaggeredGridLayout, but the limitations are as follows:

1. Requires a consistent # of spans (columns) per row. I know I could set this programmatically, but I'd need to somehow measure each object, which I don't *really* want to do, because of other limitations like #2 below
2. Even with a variable spanCount (# of columns), the gridLayout stretches each row to fill the maximum width, creating an unsightly spacing between each object.

(**see my screenshots below**)

Am I missing something huge here? Maybe I should be using a different construct entirely (like a table), but let me know if I'm missing something obvious.

RecyclerView XML:

```
                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/tagsRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"                        
                    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
                    android:rotationY="180"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tagsTxt"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paragraphTxt" />
```

Layout initialized using:

```
tagRecyclerLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

**Current look** (StaggeredGridLayout; grid stretches to fill all space, consistent # of columns (spanCount)):

[image]

**Desired look** (line-wrapping, consistent spacing, dynamic # of columns):

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use a grid Layout for this.  I would have a LinearLayout for each Row, and I would measure before adding the text.  If it wouldn't fit I would add a new row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider [`FlexboxLayout`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). Take a look at the readme at the GitHub project site. I think you will find that it will fit your needs. There is also a `FlexboxLayoutManager` for `RecyclerView`. This is all supported by Google.

You can download the GitHub project to play with it to see if you can use it. There are also some demo playground apps in the Google Play store. Just search for it.